# stress centrality in social network

Tags: networkx, python-3.6

i got the error of this code which is:
path[index][4] += 1 
IndexError: list index out of range
why this happened?how can i remove this error ?
Code:

```
def stress_centrality(g):
  stress = defaultdict(int)
  for a in nx.nodes_iter(g):
    for b in nx.nodes_iter(g):
      if a==b:
        continue
      pred = nx.predecessor(G,b)  # for unweighted graphs
      #pred, distance = nx.dijkstra_predecessor_and_distance(g,b)  # for weighted graphs
      if a not in pred:
        return [] 
      path = [[a,0]] 
      path_length = 1
      index = 0
      while index >= 0: 
        n,i = path[index] 
        if n == b: 
          for vertex in list(map(lambda x:x[0], path[:index+1]))[1:-1]:
            stress[vertex] += 1
        if len(pred[n]) >i: 
          index += 1 
          if index == path_length: 
            path.append([pred[n][i],0]) 
            path_length += 1 
          else: 
            path[index] = [pred[n][i],0] 
        else: 
          index -= 1 
          if index >= 0: 
            path[index][4] += 1 
  return stress
```

Comment: can you solve this error??@aryamccarthy

Comment: can you solve this error??....@joel

Answer (score 0):

Without the data it's hard to give you anything more than an indicative answer.

This line

```
path[index][4] += 1
```

assumes there are 5 elements in `path[index]` but there are fewer than that. It seems to me that your code only assigns or appends to `path` lists of length 2. As in

```
path = [[a,0]]
path.append([pred[n][i],0]) 
path[index] = [pred[n][i],0]
```

So it's hard to see how accessing the 5th element of one of those lists could ever be correct.

This is a complete guess, but I think you might have meant

```
path[index][1] += 4
```